# VBA Duplicate Sheet with code

Tags: vba, excel

So I have an Excel workbook that contains a template sheet for products.

I am creating new products on a Main Page via a UserForm which creates a new sheet, copies the cells from the template sheet and pastes them onto the new sheet and then fills in the rest with the information given from the UserForm.

The problem I am having is that I want each one of these newly created sheets to contain code for `Worksheet_Change`. I do not know of a way in which to create the new sheet and also give it the necessary code which is currently in the template sheet.

Any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't copy the cells to the new sheet.

Instead, copy the entire sheet.........any sheet code will copy with it.

**EDIT#1:**

For example, if worksheet "Template" contains some worksheet code, then:

```
Sub marine()
    N = Sheets.Count
    Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(N)
End Sub
```

will copy that sheet, code & all.

Comment: Adding a sample code would help the OP a lot I think. :)